# How shadow TextBlock in Wp7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, shadow

In windows phone mango, how can  i set a shadow on a TextBlock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no a `DropShadowEffect` I'm afraid.

You could try out something like this though:

With the image you can just simply create a drop shadow in Photoshop/Gimp etc (works well for me) and save it as .png.

With TextBlock it is a bit harder. For instance, create a half-transparent image with the shadow and place both TextBlock and the Image inside the Canvas. Change the Canvas.ZIndex="integer" attached property to place them in a specific order - image has to be underneath. Also shadow should be blurred.

The drawbacks are:

Shadow is static.
Doesn't really suit metro UX.